# List is not conforming to Encodable

Tags: swift, realm, swift4, codable

So, I'm using realm and I have the following relationship between two models: `A unit has many tests`:

```
 // Unit model
 class Unit: Object, Decodable {
     @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
     ...
     let tests = List<Test>()

     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
          case id
          ...
          //case tests = "complete_control_tests"
     }

     convenience required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
          self.init()
          let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
          id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
          ...
          if let arr = try container.decodeIfPresent(Array<Test>.self, forKey: .tests) {
                tests.append(objectsIn: arr)
          } else {
                self.tests.append(objectsIn: [])
          }
     }
 }
 // Test model
 class Test: Object, Decodable {
     @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
     @objc dynamic var room_control_id: String = ""

     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
          case id
          case room_control_id = "room_control_id"

     }
 }
```

When the `tests` property is commented, I can properly parse the json output for that model. But then when I uncommented it, I have the following errors:

```
Swift.Encodable:12:17: Protocol requires function 'encode(to:)' with type 'Encodable'
Models/Unit.swift:27:6: Cannot automatically synthesize 'Encodable' because 'List<Test>' does not conform to 'Encodable'
```

Is there a way to make Codable and Realm play nice?

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your code. First of all, if you only want to implement the `init(from:)` method, but not the `encode` method, declare conformance to `Decodable` rather than `Codable`. Secondly, you need to implement `CodingKeys` when creating your own `init(from:)` method and you also need to call a designated initializer of your class from a convenience initializer.

There's also no need for the `else` clause in the initializer, since `tests` is initialized as an empty `List` already and appending an empty array to it makes no sense.

```
class Unit: Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    let tests = List<Test>()

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, tests
    }

    convenience required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        if let arr = try container.decodeIfPresent(Array<Test>.self, forKey: .tests) {
            tests.append(objectsIn: arr)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my initial post with my existing code, that already contains all the points stated in your comment. Despite that, my project won't compile given the errors.

Comment: @SahbiBelgacem you are still using `Codable` rather than `Decodable`, hence the error. If you were actually using `Decodable`, you couldn't be getting that error referring to `Encodable` conformance

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my code. Instead of `Decodable`, I've written `Codable`

Comment: @SahbiBelgacem the code in your question and the error still doesn't align. You cannot get an error about `Encodable` if you only declare conformance to `Decodable`. Moreover, the code in my answer compiles without any errors, I have tested it before posting so if you would be using the same code, you wouldn't get any compiler errors.

Comment: I know! It was weird. I've cleaned the cache and now it's working. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

The first error message clearly states that if you implement custom `init` method (*decode*) you have also to implement `encode(to:)` (*encode*) to conform to the protocol.

If you are only decoding the object and you don't need to encode it adopt only `Decodable.`
Otherwise implement `encode(to:)`.

To solve the second error declare the `CodingKeys` explicitly.

Comment: Even if I use `Decodable` instead of `Codable`, I'll have the same errors !

Comment: The second error occurs because the coding key `tests` expects to decode `List<Test>` but you are decoding `Array<Test>`. Declare a property with a different name for `List<Test>` or declare the coding keys explicitly.

Comment: Because I cannot do this : `tests = try container.decode(List<Test>.self, forKey: .tests)`. That's why I use an array first then append it to tests's property.

Comment: A solution is to declare additionally `let testArray : Array<Test>` as dummy and decode `if let arr = try container.decodeIfPresent(Array<Test>.self, forKey: .testArray)` or – as already mentioned - declare the coding key(s) explicitly to separate the key from the property name.

Comment: But realm's documentation clearly state to use `list` for linking objects together !. Plus it seems to work with other users, but not for me :( . [GH: Class does not conform "Encodable" while using List<String> in swift 4.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5437#issuecomment-340499853)

Comment: Did you try my (double) suggestion to *declare the coding keys explicitly*?

Comment: If I follow your suggestion and use `var tests = Array<Test>()` instead of `List`, I can successfully compile the project and correctly parse the json.

Answer (score 1):

I've found why it's not working. It was Xcode's cache. I've deleted the contents of Xcode Derived data folder and now it's compiling and parsing the json correctly.

Sorry, folks !