# How to encode Realm's List<> type

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to encode my Realm database to JSON. Everything is working except the `List<>` encoding. So my question is, how would you encode `List<>`? Because the `List` doesn't conform to **Encodable** neighter **Decodable** protocol.

Right now I am doing this:

```
@objcMembers class User: Object, Codable{
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    let dogs = List<Dog>()


    private enum UserCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case dogs
    }

    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: UserCodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)

    }



@objcMembers class Dog: Object, Codable{
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var user: User? = nil

    private enum DogCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
    }

    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        name = name
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: DogCodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)

    }
}
```

and like this I am trying to do it:

```
var json: Any?
let user = RealmService.shared.getUsers()
var usersArray = [User]()
for user in users{
     usersArray.append(user)
}

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let encodedJson = try? jsonEncoder.encode(portfoliosArray)


        if let data = encodedJson {
            json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
            if let json = json {
                print(String(describing: json))
            }
        }
```

So the question is how I am able to encode the `List<Dog>?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List is not conforming to Encodable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619049/list-is-not-conforming-to-encodable). You can implement `Decodable` in a similar manner if you need to.

Comment: Your answer is about decoding not encoding. I gotta encode my objects, decoding is working fine. The problem is I do not kow how to encode the List<>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make a Realm object model class with a property of type `List` conform to `Encodable`, you can simply convert the `List` to an `Array` in the `encode(to:)` method, which can be encoded automatically.

```
extension User: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.username, forKey: .username)
        let dogsArray = Array(self.dogs)
        try container.encode(dogsArray, forKey: .dogs)
    }
}
```

Test classes I used (slightly different from the ones in your question, but I already had these on hand and the methods in question will be almost identical regardless of the variable names):

```
class Dog: Object,Codable {
    @objc dynamic var id:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name:String = ""
}

class User: Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var id:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var username:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var email:String = ""
    let dogs = List<Dog>()

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, username, email, dogs
    }

    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        username = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .username)
        email = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
        let dogsArray = try container.decode([Dog].self, forKey: .dogs)
        dogs.append(objectsIn: dogsArray)
    }
}
```

Test the encoding/decoding:

```
let userJSON = """
{
    "id":1,
    "username":"John",
    "email":"example@ex.com",
    "dogs":[
        {"id":2,"name":"King"},
        {"id":3,"name":"Kong"}
    ]
}
"""

do {
    let decodedUser = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: userJSON.data(using: .utf8)!)
    let encodedUser = try JSONEncoder().encode(decodedUser)
    print(String(data: encodedUser, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Output:

> {"username":"John","dogs":[{"id":2,"name":"King"},{"id":3,"name":"Kong"}]}

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! I do not know why I didn't came to the same idea :D It shouldn't affect much of performance also.

Answer (score 0):

You could resort to a mini-hack by making `List` conform to `Encodable`:

```
extension List: Encodable {
    public func encode(to coder: Encoder) throws {
        // by default List is not encodable, throw an exception
        throw NSError(domain: "SomeDomain", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
    }
}

// let's ask it to nicely encode when Element is Encodable
extension List where Element: Encodable {
    public func encode(to coder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = coder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode(contentsOf: self)
    }
}
```

Two extensions are needed as you can't add protocol conformance and `where` clauses at the same time.

Also note that this approach doesn't provide compile-time checks - e.g.  a `List<Cat>` will throw an exception an runtime if `Cat` is not encodable, instead of a nice compile time error.

The upside is lot of boilerplate code no longer needed:

```
@objcMembers class User: Object, Encodable {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    let dogs = List<Dog>()

    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}

@objcMembers class Dog: Object, Encodable {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var user: User? = nil

    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        name = name
    }
}
```

This is also scalable, as adding new classes don't require any encoding code, but with the mentioned downside of not being fully type safe at compile time.