# Realm iOS - How to Update List?

Tags: ios, realm, realm-list

I am using Codable with Realm on iOS and is finding issue with updating existing records saved in Realm. Data consists of a list of Items where each of the items has List of categories and each category has a description.

This is how my Realm Codable models look like

```
class Items: Object, Decodable {

    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    let categories =  List<Categories>()
    @objc dynamic var desc: Desc?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    var hasSubCategories: Bool {
        if self.categories.count > 0 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case desc
        case categories
    }

    required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        desc = try (container.decodeIfPresent(Desc, forKey: .desc))
        let categoriesList = try container.decodeIfPresent(List<Categories>.self, forKey: .categories) ?? List<Categories>()
        categories.append(objectsIn: categoriesList)
        super.init()
    }
}

class Categories: Object, Decodable {

    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var desc: Desc?
    let categories =  List<Categories>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    var hasSubCategories: Bool {
        if categories.count > 0 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case categories
   }

    required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        desc = try (container.decodeIfPresent(Desc, forKey: . desc))
        let categoriesList = try container.decodeIfPresent(List<Categories>.self, forKey: .categories) ?? List<Categories>()
        categories.append(objectsIn: categoriesList)
        super.init()
    }
}
```

I add new Items received from API with following code

```
let realm = try? Realm()

 for item in ItemsFromAPI {

do {
     try realm?.write {
         realm?.add(item)
       }
    }
}
```

When a data already saved in DB is received from API, I need to update it. As per my understanding, with primarykey implemented

```
realm?.add(Item, update: .modified)
```

will update the existing record which has the same primary. 
Properties of object with class Item are updated but the List<> of categories are not getting updated.

I tried to fetch existing list of categories saved in database and mutated the categories object associated with savedItem by calling `savedItem.categories.removeAll()` and added new categories with `savedItem.categories.append(objectsIn: itemFromAPI.categories)`
When i save this with

```
realm?.add(Item, update: .modified)
```

Realm crashing throwing an exception - “RLMException reason: Attempting to create an object of type with an existing primary key value”

So I tried removing the category with

```
realm?.delete(Category)
```

and then added the modified Category associated with Item and this is working.

I have nested Categories to multiple levels and updating them by fetching it again, deleting them and readding them again is proving to be a pain. Is this how update records work in realm?

Can I update the nested category related to an item by simply assigning the new object against an item and use the

```
realm?.add(Item, update: .modified)
```

to update the records like its done for adding a new item?

Any response would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think what you are asking here is how to make a Realm List property encodable, right? If so, that's been asked and answered several times here on SO. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086660/how-to-encode-realms-list-type) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452833/how-to-use-list-type-with-codable-realmswift). Check those out and see if they help as the List object is not directly codeable or decodable

Comment: No. My question is how to update a Realm List property with realm?.add(Item, update: .modified) function. It doesn't seem to update List properties.  Should I be fetching existing database entries and then delete entry, create new entry with same primarykey to update OR can I simply build the main object that holds the list with new values and update them with realm add function with update flag set?

Comment: I think I have an answer for you. Let me know if it needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Per a comment, the question is

> My question is how to update a Realm List property with
>   realm?.add(Item, update: .modified) function.

Let me restate the question for clarity

> How to update an object stored in another objects List property where the
>   stored objects in the list have a primary key

The short answer is: *a List object holds references to other objects within that list. Because it contains references, the List itself doesn't need to be updated, just the object it's referencing*

The long answer is via an example: Let's take a Person who has a List property of Dogs

```
class PersonClass: Object {
   @objc dynamic var person_id = UUID().uuidString
   let dogs = List<DogClass>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "person_id"
    }
}

class DogClass: Object {
   @objc dynamic var dog_id = NSUUID().uuidString
   @objc dynamic var dog_name = ""

   override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "dog_id"
    }
}
```

The key is that a List object contains references to the objects stored within it. It doesn't 'hold' those actual objects. If the properties of an object in a list change, the list itself is unaffected and still has a reference to that changed object.

So say our person has two dogs.

```
let person = PersonClass()

let dog0 = DogClass()
dog0.dog_name = "Spot"
let dog1 = DogClass()
dog1.dog_name = "Rover"

person.dogs.append(objectsIn: [dog0, dog1])

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(person)
}
```

so now person has two dogs; Spot and Rover.

Suppose we want to change Rovers name to Lassie. There's no need to change or update the persons list - simply update the dogs name property in realm, ensuring we use the same dog_id, and that change will be reflected in the person list.

```
let updatedDog = DogClass()
updatedDog.dog_id = "the dogs primary key"
updatedDog.dog_name = "Lassie"

try! realm.write {
   realm.add(updatedDog, update: .modified)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jay for explaining this to me. Since I am using Swift Codable with Realm, I had the advantage of getting everything parsed and consolidated in to my parent class object that holds the list. I was wondering if I could use this approach to update the parent as well as child lists associated with parent like I do for inserting new objects to Realm DB. Based on your example, I get the full person record with dog data, when dog info changes. With your approach, I will have to update person data and fetch the associated list of dogs, and loop through the individual dog to update it.

Comment: @Prabhu Often times Codable is a lot more trouble than it's worth. A good use case is if you're importing straight JSON into Swift objects, however, Realm is not Swift - it's backed by ObjC code and objects and you may find it's better to create objects with initializer code that maps to the objects properties.